# Unit Testing Monorail's RedirectToReferrer()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, castle-monorail

I am trying to write a unit test for an action method which calls the `Controller.RedirectToReferrer()` method, but am getting a "No referrer available" message.

How can I isolate and mock this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about creating a [test double](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html)?

Comment: That might help, so will a mock, I assume.

The problem is that the PrepareController() method used in Monorail controller unit tests already creates a stub, and the Response object is immutable and has no setter.

Any other ideas? (Typemock isn't an option ATM)

Answer (score 0):

In *my* version of the trunk I'm working against, r5299, I had to do this to mock out RedirectToReferrer.  I think it's been changed in recent commits, I'm not sure.

```
[TestFixture]
public class LoginControllerTests : GenericBaseControllerTest<LoginController>
{
    private string referrer = "http://www.example.org";
    protected override IMockRequest BuildRequest()
    {
        var request = new StubRequest(Cookies);
        request.UrlReferrer = referrer;

        return request;
    }

    protected override IMockResponse BuildResponse(UrlInfo info)
    {
        var response = new StubResponse(info,
                                        new DefaultUrlBuilder(),
                                        new StubServerUtility(),
                                        new RouteMatch(),
                                        referrer);
        return response;
    }
```

etc. etc.

It's oddly the *Response* that you need to molest to get the `RedirectToReferrer` to work.  I had to crawl around in the monorail sources to figure it out.